# Can't get my relative paths to work with flashDevelop and flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flashdevelop

So i am using FlashDevelop and flex but i can't get the source to work correctly. When ever i Embed a image it works just fine but if i just go source="../img/Koala.jpg" same path that i used for the working embed it doesn't work. In flash builder all i would have to do is source="/img/Koala.jpg" and it work work just fine. If i type in the path "D:\flashDevelop\FlexMobileProject\src\img\Koala.jpg" this works fine. Can anyone please explain what i'm missing here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    title="HomeView" creationComplete="init()">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        [Embed(source = "../img/Koala.jpg")]
        [Bindable] public var img:Class;


        public function init():void {
            var s:String = new String();
            label.text = String(imgstage.sourceHeight);

            trace(imgstage.source);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<!-- can't find the image even if that path is the same as the embed -->
<s:Image id="imgstage" source="../img/Koala.jpg" y="0" x="0"/>
<s:Label id="label" text="name"></s:Label>
</s:View>
```

Comment: Philippe answer is right.Also thinks about this restriction it is perfectly OK with flex (server deployment you can refer parent path ) but think about AIR. it only packaging src of AIR project directly definitely you cannot install those image in parent directory of INSTALLED DIR so it not possible with AIR (including mobile application).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify 'source' for an Image, the file will be loaded at run time. However, FlashDevelop doesn't copy the files from src/ to bin/ - you must populate the bin/ directory manually with the elements you want to load at run time. Paths at run time are resolved relatively to the HTML page.

Embeds are resolved at compile time, and it should be noted that when using FlashDevelop the path is always resolved relatively to the class/mxml file and not relatively to the project root. If the path starts with "/" it will be relative to the classpath's root.

PS: these limitations are actually in the Flex SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly the source="../img/Koala.jpg" is processed at runtime while the embed directive is processed at compile time. So the working directory is different which causes the source="" to fail.

Does the following work :

```
<s:Image id="imgstage" source="img/Koala.jpg" y="0" x="0"/>
```

Assuming the img folder is next to your swf file it should work.

Comment: no it still doesn't work. It almost seems like the file isn't even being moved into the working directory with flashDevelop is being debuged or installing the extra files like flash builder does. When i look at the bin folder in flashdevelop it just has a swc in it but when i look at the folder in flash builder (the folder called "bin-debug") it has Main-app.xml and Main.swf and folder with the photos in it. Is there a setting that I'm missing to tell it to copy the files over to the bin?

Comment: If you right click the project in FlashDevelop you can tell it to put the swf file in a specific folder.

Answer (score 0):

In FlashDevelop, whatever files that you want to keep outside the SWF have to be placed in bin folder.